# Получить дату создания базы данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Необходимо получить список баз данных с датой их создания! Имеется сервер Mysql, создано очень много баз данных года с 2014. Необходимо удалить самые старые с 2014 по 2017 года.

Пробовал выводить через `SHOW DATABASES` и `SELECT table_schema FROM information_schema.columns GROUP BY table_schema;`
Но получаю только имена.
Будет плюсом если подскажете раздел  в документации Mysql где подробно можно посмотреть инфу по базам данных.

Comment: MySQL не хранит подобную информацию - она ему просто не нужна. Смотрите даты создания каталогов БД в файловой системе сервера.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Даты создания баз данных MySQL не хранит, но хранит даты создания таблиц. Если считать датой создания базы данных дату создания первой таблицы в ней, то можно как-то так:

```
SELECT table_schema, MIN(create_time)
  FROM information_schema.tables
  GROUP BY table_schema;
```

---

Документацию по поводу того, какие данные можно получить из `information_schema` можно найти в [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html).

Comment: Все верно. Почему-то я не подумал об этом сразу! А ведь мне этот вариант подойдет! Спасибо!

Comment: Осталась мелочь - гарантировать, что таблицы не пересоздавались... впрочем, если автора это устраивает - почему бы и нет.

Comment: @unreal_serg Только, наверное, есть определённый смысл брать максимум, получая что-то вроде "последней DDL-активности в базе".